# sending user login data to c# script then to mySql then to php/html for display

Tags: c#, mysql, batch-file

I am working on a project for tracking students logon/logoff/system start/system shutdown when students use the computer lab. I have been getting some help from my searching, but I do not see anything that can help me get it all working together correctly. I have a few logon and logoff scripts that write to a .txt when I run them in the command line but not at logon? I also have been trying to get the get this to run the c# connector application I have, and also send the data to this in correctly to mySql. I know these scripts are not the best, but I am very new to this and have never used a batch file, mySql, or html so I am very lost at this point. If there is anyone that can help I would really appreciate your it!

---

batch 1  that writes to .txt

rem LogOn batch file:
   rem @echo off 
   echo "%USERNAME% Logged onto %COMPUTERNAME% AT %TIME% ON %DATE% TO SERVER
   %LOGONSERVER%;" >> c:\users\adam\desktop\%username%.txt

---

Batch 2 I try to get c# script to run at logon

```
rem @echo off 
rem echo "%USERNAME%;%TIME%;%DATE%;%COMPUTERNAME%;%LOGONSERVER%" >>      
c:\users\adam\desktop\mysqlconnector\bin\debug\mysqlsonnector.exe
```

---

sqlconnector c# I also want to try and put the collection part in here
This is what i really am stuck on

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
```

namespace mySqlConnector
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try 
        {//localhost is 127.0.0.1 and port is mySql port


            string myConnection = "datasource=" +  
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"]
                + " ;port=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerPort"]
                + " ;username=" + 
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"]
                + " ;password=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["123456"]
                + " ;time=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Time"]
                + " ;date=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Date"];

            MySqlConnection myCon = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

            //pass query labdata database using the table logdata
            myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(" select *
labdata.logs ;", myCon);
            MySqlCommandBuilder comBuil = new 
MySqlCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter);

            myCon.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connection");
            myCon.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex1.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Configuration:

Kind regards, Adam

Comment: Here is the configuration information
<configuration><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ServerName" value="localhost"/>
    <add key="ServerPort" value="3306"/>
    <add key="UserName" value="adam"/>
    <add key="Password" value ="xxxxxx"/>
    <add key="Time" value ="time"/>
    <add key="Date" value ="date"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

Comment: Hello community, did I not post this this in the right section? I have still been looking everywhere and have found some good info, but nothing that takes these steps I need. If I need to post this in a different location please let me know.